# HOW to get mail structure with part number using imap command

Tags: email, imap

There are several parts for an email which is defined by RFC822. I think that there should be different stuctures of a mail for different implementation of RFC822. Well, how to get mail structure with part numbers using imap command?

I have get an article [here](http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-imap-message-parts/), which is said:

```
Message structure

The structure of an email message is generally something like this, with part numbers:

1 - Multipart/alternative headers
1.1 - Plain text message
1.2 - HTML version of message
2 - Inline attachment, etc

In Apple Mail it's like this instead:

1 - Plain text message
2 - Multipart/alternative headers
2.1 - HTML version of the message
2.2 - Inline attachment, etc

If the message has been forwarded, then it will look like this:

1 - Multipart/alternative headers
1.1 - Plain text message
1.2 - HTML version of message
2 - Message/RFC822
2.0 - Attached message header
2.1 - Plain text message
2.2 - HTML version of message
2.3 - Inline attachment, etc

Apple Mail does it differently again, and it's more complicated. I won't bother showing it here.
```

For example, I want to know the structure of gmail. Is there any imap commands can doing this? well, some other alternative way will be fine either, such as pop command or something else?

Comment: Download the message and pass it through a mime parser, or fetch the BODYSTRUCTURE from IMAP, where the server parses the MIME for you.

Comment: FETCH BODYSTRUCTURE doesnt return part numbers.

Comment: They are implicit in the tree you construct from the response. It is a set of nested lists. The first list is 1. The first sub list of that is 1.1, and the second is 1.2 and so on.

Comment: @Max This is not always true. See Jan's answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are looking for the [`FETCH (BODYSTRUCTURE)`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501#page-55) command. It will not include any numbers because that piece of information is implicitly present -- an IMAP client is supposed to *parse* the `BODYSTRUCTURE` data and infer the actual part number from the resulting data structure. Just look at the offset of the interesting part.

It's a bit more complicated due to the way certain parts are specified to *not* be directly numbered; i.e. a `multipart/*` which consitutes the body of a `message/rfc822` does *not* get its own number, but is instead accessible as *number-of-its-parent*`.TEXT`.

Comment: Can you please link something that says that multipart messages don't get their own part numbers? RFC3501 doesn't say so I think

Comment: Look at the [example (beginning with "Here is an example of a complex message with some of its part specifiers:")](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3501#page-56), and watch out for all parts of the `multipart/mixed` MIME type. They are identified at the following locations: `TEXT`, `3.TEXT`, `4`, and `4.2.TEXT`.

That's quite irregular, don't you think?

Comment: Thanks, I see now, it's only in conjunction with `mesage/rfc822` because 4 gets its own number